# How to add calculated column to mysql query result in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, mysqli

Sorry if I am not clear in explaining this but here goes:

If I make a query from a mysql table eg.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table_name");
```

I want to keep the query structure while adding a column to it that is calculated every time using the data in the current column. The query result must be edited without appending anything to the original sql table. So if there was a column with numbers and I wanted to add 5 to every item in a new column.

So if this is the query result:

```
|Header1 | Header2 |
+--------+---------+
|0       | 1       |
|2       | 5       |
|9       | 7       |
```

I want to know how to generate another query result (same format as $result above) with another calculated column (header 3 being header 2 + 5).

```
|Header1 | Header2 | Header3 |
+--------+---------+---------+
|0       | 1       | 6       |
|2       | 5       | 10      |
|9       | 7       | 13      |
```

Sorry if this doesnt make sense, I will elaborate where possible.

Kabeer

Comment: `select header1,header2, header2+5 as header3 from table ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT Header1, (Header1 + 5) AS Header2 FROM table_name`

OR

`SELECT Header1, (Header1 + 5) AS Header2, (Header 1 + 5 + 5) AS Header3 FROM table_name`

Or did you mean something recursive? I am not 100% sure what you mean.

Comment: Thank you. 2 questions. If I wanted to do all columns plus my additional column would "SELECT *, Header3" work? Also I tried to make it simpler by just using an addition and then tailoring to my needs but if I wanted to make it the calling of a function instead of just addition would "SELECT *, function($a, Header2) as Header3" work?

Comment: Yes, if you use `SELECT *, (Header2 + 5) AS Header3` it would work :) 

I'm not sure about that, it depends what the function is - e.g. if it is one you can do within your SQL command or not. I'd suggest looking at the documentation for the function. Though, yes, provided it is part of the SQL command you can just select the result as another column.